# My point light doesn't appear in cycles render, why?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, 3d-view, light, blend-files

So I'm rendering in Cycles the DONUT, lately my renders have no light (the objects are not black but really dark) and the strange part is, that it doesn't matter what I do to my light in the viewport, because the only place the light changes in, is in the viewport (the renders keep the same dark lighting). Im new to blender and I really don't want to get discouraged by something like this, if anyone can help i'd be happy, thank you in advance.

[image: The first one is what it looks like in viewport]

[image: The second one is how the renders look like]

Here is the file for further information and details: https://we.tl/t-N9EJ2FRiXs
It's a .blend file so don't worry and thanks

Answer (score 7):

Check your *Outliner*, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything, you have a plane that is hidden in *Viewport* but not in *Render*, and it makes a big shadow on your scene.

[image]

Here you can see how the hidden plane is interfering with the light:

[image]

Comment: Damn THANKS!!!!